# iPhone 6/6 Plus: UITableView separator flickering and different thickness

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, iphone-6

I've got a `UITableView` with separator set to Single Line.

On iPhones <= 5s everything looks fine, but on 6 and 6 Plus (device as well as simulator) the separators have a different thickness. It's even worse as they're flickering while scrolling which looks pretty bad. I don't set the height manually, so I have no idea what's causing this.

[image]

As you can see, the first two lines are a little bit thicker than the next two. Now if I scroll, they change from thick to thin and back, so it looks like flickering...

Comment: Just to add more to the question I am posting a [small video](http://youtu.be/epWz5kO3N3M) of my app with similar problem. And in my case I have set my UITableViewSeperatorStyle to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone.

Comment: Try 
`cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins=NO;`


that fixed things for me.

Comment: unfortunately not for me...

Comment: cell. cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins default is NO

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that your app doesn't support native resolution for the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus. Therefore it gets scaled up which results in the flickering.

You can enable native resolution by adding iOS8 launch images. Then your app will run in the right resolution and this problem will be fixed.

Comment: Using launch images changes the UI of the whole app.

Comment: Worked! I just got rid of the launch images and used a launchscreen

Answer (score 9):

Add

```
Renders with edge antialiasing: YES
```

In you .plist file

Answer (score 2):

user3928795 is right, the thickness and flickering problems go away if you add iOS8 launch images.

But you don't need to make actual launch images if you are using storyboards.  In Xcode, select your overall project and your app target, then under the General tab find App Icons and Launch Images, then in the Launch Screen File popup, just select your storyboard and the thickness/flickering problems go away.

Comment: What if we have used xib's instead of Storyboards ?

Comment: You should be using a Launch Screen storyboard no matter what how your UI is being made - code-only, storyboards, xibs, SwiftUI, or anything else.