# ObjC strange behaviour of separator lines when scrolling a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, separator

I am having a weird situation with the separator lines of a UITableView which has been added in a UIView. The view has a backgroundColor and when I scroll the tableView it looks like it is redrawing them. In an iPhone 5 or iPod this is not happening only in iPhone 6/s

The tableView has been added through storyboard, style is plain and Separator Default

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView

Comment: can you please show it by uploading video at any site

Comment: Run on device or simulator? Is it running native.y or scaled on the 6 (do you have the correct launch images etc)?

Comment: Have you added the constraints to particular controller?

Comment: https://youtu.be/qoNv9gZlO7U

Answer (score 0):

I got it after all it was the missing images from the LaunchImages for the support of iphone 6/s

based on the following answer : 
[iPhone 6/6 Plus: UITableView separator flickering and different thickness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502773/iphone-6-6-plus-uitableview-separator-flickering-and-different-thickness)

thank you all